# columns environment, independent uncovering of items

Tags: beamer

I have no better title but feel encouraged to edit.

I have, say, the following document

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{3cm}
      Initial text. \par\pause Final text.
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{3cm}
      Important text.
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

that `latex`ed hopefully would produce a frame with two slides,

```
1st slide                         2nd slide
-------------------------------   -------------------------------
Initial text.                     Initial text.   Important text.
                                  Final text.
-------------------------------   -------------------------------
```

I would like

```
-------------------------------   -------------------------------
Initial text.   Important text.   Initial text.   Important text.
                                  Final text.
-------------------------------   -------------------------------
```

what is the trick? tia,

Comment: Don't use `\pause`. Instead put a `\visible<2->{...}` around the stuff you want to be uncovered on the second slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this one could use `\visible` in the following way:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{3cm}
      Initial text. \par
      \visible<2->{Final text.}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{3cm}
      Important text.
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```